# Accepting NULL values and inserting in SQLite Java

Tags: java, null

I am using a prepared statement to insert to my database. Some of the values im inserting are NULL as the matches are yet to be played, and so the score is NULL, NULL.

```
void insertFixtures(List<String[]> fixtures) throws SQLException{
    String query = "REPLACE INTO games (team1_id, team2_id, score1, score2, created_at, winner) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Connection con = DBConnector.connect();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

    for (String[] s : fixtures) {
        try{
            stmt.setString(1,s[0]);
            stmt.setString(2,s[1]);
            Integer score1 = s[2] != null ? Integer.parseInt(s[2]) : null;
            Integer score2 = s[3] != null ? Integer.parseInt(s[3]) : null;
            stmt.setInt(3, score1);
            stmt.setInt(4, score2);
            stmt.setString(5,s[4]);
            String date = s[4];
            int winner;
            int dateValue = Integer.parseInt(date); 

            if (score1 > score2 && dateValue != 0) {
                winner = 1;
            } else if (score2 > score1 && dateValue != 0) {
                winner = 2;
            } else if(dateValue != 0) {
                winner = 0;
            } else {
                winner = 3;
            }

            String gameWinner = Integer.toString(winner);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stmt.execute();         
    }
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
```

InsertFixtures takes the list string array and inserts these into my database using a for loop.
The problem i have is with:

```
This is the print stack trace of the NullPointerException i get.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at footballresults.MashapeClient.insertFixtures(MashapeClient.java:130)
    at footballresults.MashapeClient.main(MashapeClient.java:190)
```

at line 130 is the code:

```
Integer score1 = s[2] != null ? Integer.parseInt(s[2]) : null;
```

Here im trying to parse the string from the array as an integer, unless it equals null i want it to be inserted into the database as null. Because the dateValue is 0 for games played it shouldn't move into the winner if statements.

This is an example of the strings im trying to insert into my database:

```
Fixture 45 42 1 0 1554642300 
Fixture 49 48 null null 0
```

Any help is useful.
Thanks

Comment: `Integer score1 = (s[2] != null && !s[2].equals("null")) ? Integer.parseInt(s[2]) : null;`. Its (null) coming as string.

Comment: Im now getting a nullPointerException on where i setInt the score1 and score2 to the statement beneath these values, but i was definitely reading it as a string thanks!